# increase button when value coming from sharedpreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-edittext, counter, android-button

I have editText in Activity. I used SharedPreference for saving this value and get later. I passed this edittext value to another activity button text. I need to increment button while text coming from edittext. But the problem is if i enter text, test then button is created with test text. If i create test1 then button test is replace with test1. I need to show test & test1 with two buttons.

code:

Activity:

```
et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);

        et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);

        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("sample",0);
                      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                     editor.putString("Name",et.getText().toString());
                     editor.putString("Name1",et1.getText().toString());

                      editor.commit();

                      Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this, Activity1.class);
                      startActivity(intent);

}


});
```

Activity1:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);

        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("sample",0);
        String Namestr=(preferences.getString("Name",""));

        String newString="";

          if(Namestr.length()>0&& Namestr.equalsIgnoreCase(newString)){

              newString=Namestr;

              Button button = new Button(Get.this);

             // button.setText("hellow");
              button.setText(preferences.getString("Name", ""));
            layout.addView(button);
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linear"    >
```

It displays only one button. If i enter test it displays the button with test text, then i enter test2 it replace the test with test2. I don't want to replace text i need to create new button with test2.

Comment: It is b'coz of sharedPreference keep the value in key pair. So for 1 key only one value will be updated. So its better to use Table to store EditText value.

Comment: Can you check my edited question. How can i store everytime edittext enter values in table

Comment: but String Namestr=(preferences.getString("Name","")); this will return only single value. Its not a array of String.

Comment: how can i use multiple value from edittext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
        EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final Map<String, String> demomap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                demomap.put(et.getText().toString(), et.getText().toString());
                SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("sample",
                        0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                for (Entry<String, String> entry : demomap.entrySet()) {
                    editor.putString(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                }
                editor.commit();

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        secondactvity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

**secondActivity.java**

```
public class secondactvity extends Activity {

    private HashMap<String, String> demomap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        demomap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("sample", 0);
        for (Entry<String, ?> entry : preferences.getAll().entrySet()) {
            demomap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().toString());
        }
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
        Iterator myVeryOwnIterator = demomap.keySet().iterator();
        while (myVeryOwnIterator.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) myVeryOwnIterator.next();
            String value = (String) demomap.get(key);
            Button button = new Button(this);
            button.setText(value);
            layout.addView(button);
        }

        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now i hope its problem is solved.

Comment: It's now showing anything. And also we need to show button with change scale.

Comment: you can change any property of button.and you can show any of the control which you want.

Comment: It's nothing showing. can you see my edited question with xml code

Answer (score 0):

You have to create Button dynamically like,

Button btn=new Button(this);
//Set buttons property and Layout params as you need.

Comment: You didn't understand my question.

Comment: for that you have to write code to distinguish that values which are coming from edittext. Compare old value and new value when you found difference at that time create new button.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code as a reference, and develop your own logic.

```
 String newString="";

     if(Namestr.length()>0 && Namestr.equalIgnoreCase(newString)){

    newString=namestr;
    //YOUR STUFF

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Now i created different key for storing your data. 
say Name1, Name2 like wise**

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("sample",0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putInt("Count", 5);//say

            for(int i=1; i<=5;i++)
            {
                editor.putString("Name"+i,et.getText().toString());
            }

            editor.commit();
```

**For Retrieving**

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("sample",0);
        int count=preferences.getInt("Count", 0);
        for(int i=1;i<=count;i++)
        {
            Button button = new Button(this);
            button.setText(preferences.getString("Name"+i, ""));
            layout.addView(button);
        }
```

Hope this will work for you.
But instead of sharedPreference use Database to store this.